# How can I pass an int to my onDraw in Android? Whats wrong in my code?

Tags: android, put, ondraw

in my example project :ondraw need an int to drawing from main activity, when initialize the parameter to 1 in mainActivity, its not draw anything,

//class MyView extends View

```
 private int parameter=0;//if i change to 1 it will draw,
//but i want set it from main Activity

    public void setParameter(int param)
    {
        this.parameter=param;
        invalidate();
        Log.i("tag9", this.parameter+" setParameter");
    }

            @Override
            protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
                Log.i("tag9",parameter + " ondraw");

                if(this.parameter==0){
                    return;}
        //Drawing code ...
            }
```

//in MainActivity:

```
MyView myView = new MyView(this);
        myView.setParameter(1);
```

//Xml code:

```
<RelativeLayout ...>


    <view
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        class="(packagename).MyView"
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="138dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

//DDMS

```
1 setparameter
0 ondraw  // its shouldnt be 0;
```

Comment: Are you adding it to a layout somewhere?  I don't see it being put on screen in the code you posted.

Comment: i add it from xml design\customView

Comment: No you aren't.  You're creating it via new.  That creates a new view not in any layout.  If you want to reference a view set in xml, use findViewById

Comment: thnx;  MyView myView = (MyView)this.findViewById(R.id.view);
  myView.setParameter(0);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thnx to Gabe Sechan ,
You're creating it via new. That creates a new view not in any layout. If you want to reference a view set in xml, use findViewById –  Gabe Sechan

```
    MyView myView = (MyView)this.findViewById(R.id.view);
    myView.setParameter(1);
```